# PHP: How to redirect if any file path is accessed directly in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the path which i have secure details say for eg., 
`http://localhost/application/secure_details` 
`secure_details` is the folder where my confidential files get uploaded.
The Third Person who knows the above URL can able to get the particular details, 
This not should be allowed. i need to redirect to `error_page` if the person is directly accessing this particular URL.

Comment: A better option might be to actually put the directory _outside_ the reachable (e.g. www-data dir) directory, and access it in code with an absolute bath.

Comment: Please read the manual of your webserver to learn how to configure it: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect - Also helps you to prevent getting answers from "programmers" that try to slaughter everything with `mod_rewrite` and regex'es in configuration.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the software's manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mod_rewrite`, add this to your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^application/secure_details/?.*?$ /error.html [L,R=301]
```

Additionally, add this `.htaccess` file to the `secure_details` directory:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: hai Cobra, when i put RewriteRule ^nuvia_test/formuploads/?$ /error_page.php [L,R=301] to my .htaccess it redirects to http://localhost/xampp but i need to redirect to error_page.php

Comment: hello Cobra_Fast, the above solution is for folders, if to unaccess any files how to do for eg http://localhost/application/secure_details/bank.txt should not be accessed, do u have any idea?

Comment: @MohanRaj I've updated the `RewriteRule` line to redirect anything within that directory.

Comment: Thanks. It works well, and also i don't like to third party users to view my folders for eg, application/views all the folders are listed, and this also should be prevented, do u have any idea?

Comment: @MohanRaj Add `Options -Indexes`

Comment: -1 Answer giving contains unneeded side-effects and even contradicting configurations.

Comment: @hakre What? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable rewrite module in apache for working with `htaccess`. After that you can make secure your url using the following script

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/*application/secure_details error.php[L,NC,QSA]
```

In `error.php` file you can write your error message